# Can not pass Data To ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uicontainerview, pass-data

I have tried 2 methods to pass the data from ViewController to ContainerView, with and without segue
Here is without segue method

**ViewController**

```
 class DetailPostBookReviewVC: UIViewController {

        var postid: String!

        @IBAction func Menubutton(_ sender: Any) {

        print(postid!)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuBookReviewVC") as! MenuBookReviewVC

        vc.favpostid = postid
 }
```

**ContainerView**

```
class MenuBookReviewVC: UIViewController {

    var favpostid = String()
     @IBAction func Deletepost(_ sender: Any) {
        print(favpostid)
    }
}
```

result: `favposid` has Nill Value

**UPDATE** this is with segue method

```
class DetailPostBookReviewVC: UIViewController {

     var postid: String! 

     @IBAction func Menubutton(_ sender: Any) {       
        print(postid!)

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if (segue.identifier == "toMenuBookReviewVC") { //"toMenuBookReviewVC" is identifier 

       let vc = segue.destination as! MenuBookReviewVC
        vc.favpostid = postid!
    }
}
```

Comment: How you push MenuBookReviewVC? Via storyboard?

Comment: How you doing with segue?

Comment: Ketan Parmar: i used func prepareForSegue for segue method but failed

Comment: have you set segue from button to view controller? or view controller to view controller? If you have set vc to vc then you need to call `performSegue` on button click. And make sure you have set `identifier` of the segue and yo're using that identifier in the code!

Comment: do you mean I create func prepareFor Segue and create one more func performSegue, putting to Button Action?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data like. User prepare(for:sender:)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if
        segue.identifier == "MyIdentifierInStorybiard", // Set that
        let controller = segue.destination as? MenuBookReviewVC {
        controller.favpostid = postid
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but unfortunately failed. My container view is a slide up menu. When I click the Menubutton, it will come up. So I think I dont use push viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I think you postid is not String type so print the null value

Comment: postid is a varible String type I declared on another VC. I did print postid successfully and show the id as String

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can't pass data for the container view. if in this way without presenting controller and push controller you can use the global variable then direct pass data and use any controller you want to use.

Example

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var postid: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        postid = "23" // You change your post ID

    }
    
    @IBAction func Menubutton(_ sender: Any) {

        favpostid = postid
        
    }
        
}



var favpostid : String!

class MenuBookReviewVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(favpostid)
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

For Passing Data To Container View you can use this

**UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "SomeKey")**

after your data is used you can clear that default value.

**UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "SomeKey")**

Comment: Fatal! Do not  do that